# Record number constraint in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have a collection with this schema:

```json
{
  "sub": 1234,
  "appId": 5678
}
```

The `sub` field is the user account id, and `appId` application id.

Now we need to limit the number of applications per user account to some value (let's say, 5). What is the easiest way?

Of course we could introduce transaction in mongodb as we do in SQL. Since we choose a document database, is there any more advanced way to this requirement?

Comment: With a document data model you can approach this issue with a different data design. The relationship between the account id and the application id is one to many - and the many side has a limited and bound data. So, for each account store an array of application ids in an array field. When you create the first document for an account id _or_ account id with its first application id, the array is created with 5 elements - pre-populated with empty values (optionally with first element). Each time a new application id is to be inserted, there will be an update operation to populate the array...

Comment: [continued...] The update operation can check the array status and add new application data, and in case the array has reached its limit, abort the update and send a message (as per application needs). This can be achieved as an atomic operation - for the initial document creation as well as the each update. Note that all write operations on a single document in MongoDB are atomic.

Comment: Wonderful! Please turn it to an answer.

Comment: What if the requirement is upgraded? For instance, free users can create 5 apps, vip 20, vvip no-limit. What is the best solution?

Comment: That will require additional data in your document  - identifying the user type. Depending upon the type the number of apps. That said, having "no limit" needs to be limited in some way (for example, 1000 apps or even 10000 apps). Because, unlimited array elements (or unknown amount of data) is not recommended.